# Map without pins / icons

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to decide if the Google Maps API is the right tool to use for me.
I have a list of places I'd like to display on a map (a map of Italy)
and I'd like that:

1. The map doesn't show any other label but mines, and
2. My places are shown as labels on the map, without any icon/pin

I saw (e.g. [Changing markers icons in Google Maps application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924382/changing-markers-icons-in-google-maps-application/3924458#3924458)) that you can change the pin icons, but I'd like not to have any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [styled map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) with the Google Maps API v3 (or a completely [custom map with your own tiles](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#CustomMapTypes))

If you just want text labels for your places, look at the [InfoBox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html) library ([this example](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/examples/infobox-label.html)).

Comment: thanks for the answer, from the links provided I think that's what I needed. Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to implement it without using JavaScript - which I dont know (any python/perl alternative would be so welcome!)

Answer (score 4):

1. Style the map to remove all other labels - I like using this [wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/). Note the 'More Options' link in the bottom left gives many more customization options.
2. To create markers with only labels, not pins, you'll need a transparent PNG to use for the marker icon. I used a 20x20 one. Tweak the icon anchor to move the label to the right spot, I found 7,7 to be reasonable. For more about custom icons, see the [docs.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex)

   ```
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: markerPosition,
         map: map,
         icon: {
             origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
             anchor: new google.maps.Point(7, 7),
             url: transparentIconURL
         },
         label: '1'
       });
   ```